# Get namespace quotas using k8s client-go

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client, client-go

I am looking for a way to get resource quotas for the namespace using client-go, similar to `kubectl describe ns my-namespace-name`.

I have tried `ns, err := k8client.CoreV1().Namespaces().Get("my-namespace-name", metav1.GetOptions{})` but it does not give quota info.

Also tried `ns, err := k8client.CoreV1().ResourceQuotas("my-namespace-name").Get("name", metav1.GetOptions{})` but I can not figure out what to put as `name` parameter in .Get(). Tried namespace name, tried several resource types from https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#resource-types but no luck with errors like `resourcequotas "namespaces" not found` or 
`resourcequotas "limits.cpu" not found`

Tried `ns, err := k8client.CoreV1().ResourceQuotas("my-namespace-name").List(metav1.ListOptions{})` as well but it returned no result.

Any ideas on how to get it will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some debugging and going through kubernetes and kubectl code, the way to get it is: 
`ns, err := k8client.CoreV1().ResourceQuotas("my-namespace-name").List(metav1.ListOptions{})`

Not sure why it did not work for me first time I have tried, might have made a typo in namespace name.